# %20 is added instead of spaces

Tags: codeigniter, urlencode, urldecode

I guess this is small issue but yet i had to ask here since i am running short in my project. When I pass string to the function in another controller, it changes spaces into %20 sign. I guess the controller thinks the string passed as url and encodes it. But I don't know exactly how to remove it or if possible do not let it to change spaces into %20. Here is the code which i use;

```
$message="The user name you provided is already in our database";
redirect('admin/add_user/'.$message);
```

Here is my controller function where i receive the message;

```
public function add_user($message)
{
  echo $message;
}
```

I also tried this as;

```
public function add_user()
{
  echo $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

But the result is same. Here is the output of the string;

```
The%20user%20name%20you%20provided%20is%20already%20in%20our%20database
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function add_user($message)
{
  echo urldecode($message);
}
```

You can read more about urldecode here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo urldecode($message);
```

because you are passing the message as part of the URL (The redirect does a new http request) it is automatically url encoded. You just need to decode it once the server receives it.

Answer (score 0):

When saving to the database use:

```
htmlentities($variable)
```

when outputing use:

```
echo html_entity_decode($variable, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```