# Codeigniter 3.0.1 Active Record db prefix not added to field name when using space in like query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I think I have discovered a bug and am looking for a way to fix this.

I am using CI 3.0.1. The problem happens when I have a space in my search parameter for a like query. This causes `items.name` to NOT have a prefix in the where clause.  (It should be `phppos_items`.`name`)

Is this considered a bug or is there a workaround?

ACTIVE RECORD CODE: (Notice search = 'test')

```
$search = 'test';
$this->db->select("items.*,categories.name as category");
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = items.category_id','left');
$this->db->where('items.deleted',0);
$this->db->like('items.name', $search);
$this->db->limit($limit);
$by_name = $this->db->get();

echo $this->db->last_query();
```

QUERY RESULT:

```
SELECT `phppos_items`.*, `phppos_categories`.`name` as `category` 
FROM `phppos_items` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_categories` ON `phppos_categories`.`id` = `phppos_items`.`category_id` 
WHERE `phppos_items`.`deleted` =0 AND `phppos_items`.`name` LIKE '%test%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 100
```

ACTIVE RECORD CODE: (notice search is test 2)

```
$search = 'test 2';
$this->db->select("items.*,categories.name as category");
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = items.category_id','left');
$this->db->where('items.deleted',0);
$this->db->like('items.name', $search);
$this->db->limit($limit);
$by_name = $this->db->get();
```

Query Result

```
SELECT `phppos_items`.*, `phppos_categories`.`name` as `category` 
FROM `phppos_items` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_categories` ON `phppos_categories`.`id` = `phppos_items`.`category_id` 
WHERE `phppos_items`.`deleted` =0 AND items.name LIKE '%test 2%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 100
```

Here is somewhat of a fix; but CI should fix this so I don't have to do this:

```
        $this->db->select("items.*,categories.name as category", false);
        $this->db->from('items');
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = items.category_id','left');
        $this->db->where('items.deleted',0);
        $this->db->like($this->db->dbprefix('items').'.name', $search);
        $this->db->limit($limit);
```

Comment: can you try putting `%20` in place of the space?

Comment: That works but that is not really what I am searching for. I hacked around it by adding the prefix explicitly but I think this is a bug.

Comment: You may be right; here's an instance of it happening the other way around:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475645/20-is-added-instead-of-spaces  You might want to check the CI site for this.

Comment: in the meantime you may wish to write a function to convert spaces into %20

Comment: another thing to try, you might want to see what happens if you change your search string to this: `$search = '"test 2"';`

Comment: @nomistic the link above is not related to this issue. The issue is caused by spaces in the 2nd parameter of a like query. When searching a database you would most likely not search for a url encoded value (%20). I have posted the issue with CI team at https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4086 Also I tried doing the quote '"TEST 2"' and it didn't work

Comment: ok, good luck.  I hope you get some resolution

Comment: Confirmed a bug and a patch has been made and scheduled for 3.0.2 see  https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/348a2d445b9d059aab4f5113a380f05eb2cd92d9

Comment: Nice work.  Have they indicated a release date, or do you need to find a workaround?

Comment: Not sure what the release date is; but I already have a workaround shown in my question. I could also patch my current version; but I don't really need to do it as of now.

Answer (score 1):

There is [confirmed bug in CI 3.0.1](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4086) when using table prefixes and the fix was released with 3.0.2 (but you should upgrade to the latest 3.0.x release).

The workaround on 3.0.1 is to use an explicit table prefix as shown here:

```
$this->db->select("items.*,categories.name as category", false);
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = items.category_id','left');
$this->db->where('items.deleted',0);
$this->db->like($this->db->dbprefix('items').'.name', $search);
$this->db->limit($limit);
```